# Add feature from one collection to another in MongoDB using the Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have two collections `users` and `groups` which are related to another. A user can only be in one group, while a group can contain multiple users.

`Document A in users`

```
{
  _id: 1234,
  name: "John Doe"
}
```

`Document B in users`

```
{
  _id: 2345,
  name: "Jane Roe"
}
```

`Document G in groups`

```
{
  _id: 3456,
  name: "A Group",
  members: [ObjectId("1234"), ObjectId("2345")]
}
```

Now I want to use the Aggregation Pipeline on the collection `users` to add the field `_group` to every user for further processing. The added field should contain the ID of the group the user is part of.

`Result for Document A`

```
{
  _id: 1234,
  name: "John Doe",
  _group: ObjectId("3456")
}
```

`Result for Document B`

```
{
  _id: 2345,
  name: "Jane Roe",
  _group: ObjectId("3456")
}
```

I don't really know where to start and how to combine the two collections in the way I described it.

Comment: So you wanted to update collection ! what is your DB version ?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/ does this.

Comment: I don't want to modify the original collections, I only needed the merge during aggregation for further processing. The accepted answer explains exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem (https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iu53HQbi7Me):

**Test data:**

```
// users collection
[
    {
      _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      name: "John Doe"
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      name: "Jane Roe"
    }
]

// groups collection
[
    {
      _id: 100,
      name: "A Group",
      members: [
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
      ]
    }
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.users.aggregate([
// join the two collections
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "groups",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "members",
      "as": "membersInfo"
    }
  },
// unwind the membersInfo array
  {
    $unwind: "$membersInfo"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": {
        $cond: {
          "if": {
            $in: [
              "$_id",
              "$membersInfo.members" // replace _id field based on the members
            ]
          },
          "then": "$_id",
          "else": "No group"
        }
      },
      "name": 1, // mantain this field
      "_group": "$membersInfo._id" // create _group field using the _id of groups collection
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_group": 100,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "_group": 100,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "name": "Jane Roe"
  }
]
```